# Can't access form variable with php

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, input

I'm new to Web development and have been messing around with `BootStrap`. I've been trying to make a Web form on my new website, but I can't seem to access the username variable.

Here's my form code:

```
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" action="username">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
    </form>
```

And here's my `index.php` in the username folder:

```
    <?php
        echo $_POST['username'];
        echo 'fail';
        echo 'username';
        if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
            $name = $_POST['username'];
            echo 'success';
        }
    ?>
```

With my debugging, I get the message fail to show up, but not the username, so I assume I am doing something wrong either with setting the username, or accessing it.

Comment: Wrong value of the `action` attribute in your form. It should be the name of the file where your PHP code is stored. Also, you haven't specified the `method` attribute which should preferrably be `post`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the following mistakes

1. You didn't set the `method` attribute in your form.So when the form is submitted the data will be posted via get method.And you need to access `$_GET` variable for getting the form data. So here when you submit the form the data will be in `$_GET` variable.But you are trying to access `$_POST` variable in your code.So you can try like setting the method attribute to `method="post` in your form and continue with the same code in index.php or try changing `$_POST` to $_GET` in your index.php and making no changes in your form
2. You are definging the code in index.php when the form is submitted.So you need to set the `action="index.php"` in your form

So it will be like this finally

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" action="username/index.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
</form>
```

index.php

```
 <?php
        echo $_POST['username'];
        echo 'fail';
        echo 'username';
        if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
            $name = $_POST['username'];
            echo 'success';
        }
    ?>
```

OR

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" action="username/index.php">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
</form>
```

index.php

```
<?php
    echo $_GET['username'];
    echo 'fail';
    echo 'username';
    if(isset($_GET['username'])) {
        $name = $_GET['username'];
        echo 'success';
    }
?>
```

Comment: If `username` is folder as OP said it should be `action="/username/"`

Answer (score 2):

According to your description, your HTML code should look something like this:

```
<form method="post" class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" action="username/index.php">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
</form>
```

You could also use `<input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Search"/>` instead of `<button type="submit"></button>`.

Answer (score 0):

Set your `action` attribute to `index.php` and set your `method="post"` if you access the username with `$_POST['username']`.